# Kepler's Second Law: conservation of the energy or of the angular momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, conservation-laws, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Reading from example the old question, [Angular Momentum and Kepler's Second Law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225348/angular-momentum-and-keplers-second-law)

Considering that now I not remember the proof because starting from the **angular moment conservation** of $L$ we have the

$$v_pr_p = v_ar_a \tag 1$$

I wish to know the reason, with the physics or mathematical steps, because not can be the **conservation of mechanical energy**.

I can explain, easily, the $(1)$ with the perihelion and aphelion speeds and the respective distances of the vector radius from the Sun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply both sides of your equation by the mass and you have equality of the magnitude of the angular momentum at the perigee and the apogee. At these points the velocity is perpendicular to the position, so $|\mathbf{L}|=|\mathbf{r}\times m\mathbf{v}|=mvr$.

In modern language, Kepler’s Second Law expresses the conservation of angular momentum, not the conservation of energy. But it’s often  stated in terms of *geometry*, as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Second_law):

> A line joining a planet and the Sun sweeps out equal areas during equal intervals of time.

To see the connection between this area-related statement of the Second Law and the conservation of angular momentum, recall that the magnitude of the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Geometric_meaning) between two vectors is the area of the parallelogram that they form. One half of this is the area of the triangle that they form.

Imagine the triangle swept out over time $dt$ by the position vector $\mathbf{r}$ as it changes by $\mathbf{v}dt$. The infinitesimal area swept out is

$$dA=\frac12|\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{v}dt|$$

because one side of the triangle is $\mathbf{r}$ and another side is $\mathbf{v}dt$.

Thus

$$\frac{dA}{dt}= |\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{v}|=\frac{|\mathbf{L}|}{m}=\text{constant}.$$

So the rate at which the area is swept out is constant because the angular momentum is constant.

Comment: Thank you very much for the first part with sincerity.  Why not can be the conservation of mechanical energy the 2nd Kepler's law?

Comment: Because energy and angular momentum are two different things. Kepler’s Law expresses the conservation of angular momentum, not the conservation of energy.

Comment: Please, is it possibile to explain with mathematical-physical steps your previous comment? Thank you very much in the meantime. Can I have your further contribute, please?

Comment: I’ve added an explanation of how the “area law” relates to the conservation of angular momentum.

Comment: I thank you very much again with the approvation and the upvoted of your answer.